# Wildcard expansion for a pattern recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a rule for make that effectively does "In order to make any `<dir>/out`, append all `<dir>/<num>/source`, *making them if necessary*".  In other words, I need to expand a list of all directories `<dir>/<num>/`, and add `source` to each, placing that as the prerequisite.

My attempt is

```
%/out : $(addsuffix source, $(wildcard %/*/))
    cat $^ > $@
```

But the `$(wildcard %/*/)` doesn't expand.  `%` does not appear to be defined the way I would like at that point (it's a literal `%`) -- how can I fix this?

I have no *a priori* knowledge of what directories this will be run on, or how many `<num>` subdirectories it will find.

Comment: You need [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) for this directly. (There are probably other ways of doing this too but that's the most direct from what you already tried.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of directories that can contain `out` files, you can generate a separate rule for each of them.

You could hard-code such a list, or generate it.

```
dirs = $(patsubst %/1, %, $(shell find -type d -name 1))
$(foreach %, $(dirs), $(eval $%/out: $(wildcard $%/*/source) ; cat $$^ > $$@))
```

I don't recommend using secondary expansion because it also would change the semantics of all other rules.